# Facebook share not working Dynamically created page in vue js

Tags: javascript, facebook, vue.js

I want to share my products using facebook sharing. I used vue js for front end development.
this is my code. I used social sharing library.This is my share button code.

```
     <social-sharing
      :url="'https://www.airbuddyhub.com/view-request/'+ItemDetails.id"
       inline-template
    >
    <network network="facebook">
    <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
    </network>
    </social-sharing>
   </div>
```

vue js is a single page application. So it has only one index file. facebook need to meta tag for get data. So I used "vuemeta" library for dynamically  generate meta tags.
I add this code inside the script tags in the same components.

```
    return {
      title: "AirbuddyHub",
      titleTemplate: "%s - items",
      meta: [
        { charset: "utf-8" },
        {
          property: "og:title",
          content: this.ItemDetails.item_name +" -  Rs "+this.ItemDetails.will_pay
        },
        { property: "og:type", content: "website" },
        {
          property: "og:url",
          content: "https://www.airbuddyhub.com/view-request/"+this.$route.params.id
        },
        {
          property: "og:description",
          content: this.ItemDetails.item_description
        },
        {
          property: "og:image",
          content:
            "https://airbuddyimage.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/PostRequest/"+this.img1
        },
        { property: "og:site_name", content: "AirbuddyHub" },
      ]
    };
  },
```

After that I added my fb app id and sdk in my main index file.

```
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId: "2088241224810720",
          autoLogAppEvents: true,
          xfbml: true,
          version: "v5.0"
        });
      };
    </script>
<script
      async
      defer
      crossorigin="anonymous"
      src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v5.0&appId=1113427062193399&autoLogAppEvents=1"
    ></script>
```

But its not work.Can you guys help me to do this?meta tags also appear inside  header tags.but not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook ignores JavaScript, so it will not get the Open Graph Data if you only set it with JavaScript. You have to provide it server side, options are [SSR](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/ssr.html) (Server Side Rendering) or [prerender.io](https://prerender.io/).